# Meaning of 折らで in a haiku

Tags: grammar, classical-japanese, literature

From Basho:

> 蓮池や折らでそのまま玉祭

I have the impression that 折らで would be 折らないで without ない. If that's the case is it an artistic choice or some obscure grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In classical Japanese, で after an irrealis-form (未然形) means ないで in modern Japanese. So 折らで means 折らないで or "without snapping off".

> #### [で](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7)
>
> 接続助詞
>
> 《接続》活用語の未然形に付く。**〔打消の接続〕…ないで。…ずに。**

This で is surviving as part of [ならでは](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-nara-dewa/) (etymologically, copula-なり + で + contrastive-は → "unless so", "if it were not" → "unique to", "found only in")

Comment: Thanks!  But could you elaborate that part about ならでは？

Comment: @naruto What resource is your definition from?

Comment: @AlbertoAndrade ならでは is a grammar pattern; see the link and the edit.

Comment: @sazarando From [学研全訳古語辞典](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7).